# Remote Desktop Services connection refused

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2012, rds

I was able to connect to my rds through chrome,IE,Firefox. Sometimes the connection would be refused. Now it is just refusing all connections, I'll be able to supply any information needed.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, I took it off of DHCP for a test and it got a duplicate IP when I re-assigned it . All is good now !